# RHEL6.6 in which file you put the gateway configuration

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

In RHEL6.6 OS system, which file we've to put the gateway configuration?
I tried GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in these files :

```
/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

and I tried the system-config-network tools as well.
No result, I 've to configure manually with `route add` command.
I've to configure 2 gateway on eth1 and eth0.

Comment: You can put the route command in `/etc/rc.local` until you find out about where to properly configure this. Then at least the gateway will be setup after a reboot.

Comment: Do you get no default route at all, or do you get a default route that goes via eth1?

Comment: Does ifcfg-eth0 have the line `NM_CONTROLLED="yes"` in it?